# How to skip login screen?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, login-screen

I have Ubuntu Gnome 15.10. I installed lightdm using this command: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm`. But when I reboot/restart the PC now I get the login screen where I can choose between **gnome 3** and the **gnome classic**. How can I skip the login screen directly to gnome 3?

PS: I am a new GNU/Linux user. Thank you!

Comment: There should be an option under Settings>>Display or Settings>Security to enable automatic login.

Comment: On which DE? I use gnome 3 and I want to use gnome 3 in the future. I do not find what you suggested.

Comment: Oh, it's under Settings>>User Accounts>>Your User. Sorry

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much! it was a little trick :D

Comment: Great! I'll put it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open System Settings and go into User Accounts. Select your user, and there should now be an option on the right to enable automatic login. Turn that on and you're done.